# how to import react components which are individual react app projects

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

In our team we have one core team which develops the main ui(we have header, sidemenu, main-content and footer) which end user will launch and use. And the content for main-content component in this UI is developed by different team members as separate react projects and they make different api calls to different microservices based on what they do. Based on the sidemenu item selected i should render the external react project as content of my main-content component.

- One way to solve this is to use iframe by hosting other react
  projects on a server and use their urls.
- Other way is to store my dependent react components in a storage and refer them in the main component with separate npm install command `npm install --save devops_repo_url/master`

We use azure devops to maintain all our react repos. What is the effective way to import other components which are not reusable anywhere else except in main component but they are different projects.  (Please note that my external components are NOTsimple ui elements like button,input ,seect etc...)

Comment: It doesn't matter if your external components are simple or complex - they take props, end of story. I'm not a fan of iframes due to latency, memory consumption and potentially duplication of shared resources, but you also have to rebuild and redeploy every time a component in the devops repo gets released (which is probably fine anyway). I'd just import them like any other dependency.

Comment: If i am not wrong, you are suggesting use them as any other npm package by installing  them with npm install and importing them wherever required.

Comment: that is correct